# Merging signed pdf with other pdfs

Tags: .net, pdf, merge

I am currently using itextsharp dll to merge pdfs documents into one document. The problem is itextsharp skips any pdfs that are digitally signed and copy not allowed pdfs during merge.

Is there any other paid or free libraries that can merge signed pdfs with non signed into a single pdf document?

Thanks,
Developer.

Comment: You are aware that merging signed PDFs will invalidate the signatures?

Comment: It turned out that signed documents are also encrypted with proprietary Adobe LiveCycle encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge signed and non signed documents using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

Here is a sample that shows how to merge two PDF documents:

```
public static void MergeFiles(string output, params string[] inputFiles)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument())
    {
        foreach (string file in inputFiles)
            doc.Append(file);

        // delete the first (automatically inserted) page
        doc.RemovePage(0);

        doc.Save(output);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(output);
    }
}
```

The library will merge bookmarks, form fields, annotations etc. But please note that digital signatures will be invalidated.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Comment: I tried the above and when i tried opening the file to append the document, I got Unsupported encryption algorithm error.

Comment: @user3446186 Please contact support@bitmiracle.com. You might have found a bug.

Comment: thanks for your input, I have send an email with details to the support email shared.